# How does this program create a 2D Array using malloc in C

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, malloc

How does the following program work to initialize a 2D Array, store data in it and then calculate the sum of all the elements.

I am actually bothered about how dynamic memory allocation is actually working in this code.

This approach is new to me as I couldn't find any resource that could explain this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define col 5
int main(){
    int n, i, j, sum =0;
    int (*a) [col];
    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    a = (int (*)[col])malloc(n * col * sizeof(int));

    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for (j=0; j < col ; ++j){
            //pointer to 5 elements row
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
            sum+= a[i][j];
        }
    }

    printf("Sum : %d\n",sum);

    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **C and C++ are different programming languages.** Choose one. Your [mre] is in C. Read [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) and **read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) if you want to learn C. Read also the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...)**

Comment: This is not how arrays of this sort are usually defined. The `int (*a)[col]` definition is usually expressed as `int**a`, or even better, a 1D array is used, and then 2D emulation is applied.

Comment: Also, [malloc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory) can fail, and your code does not handle that failure. Of course [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) can also fail, and your code does not handle that case. If you use [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile with all warnings and debug info, so use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`.  With [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) you can observe the dynamic behavior of your program by running it [step by step](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html)

Comment: What does the line ```a = (int (*)[col])malloc(n * col * sizeof(int));```  do ? Can someone explain please.

Comment: @PrathPratimChaterjee: **What book did you read on C programming?** The answer is inside such books, and dozen of pages are needed for an explanation. We won't write these for you alone. You might also dive inside the source code of simple C compilers, such as [nwcc](http://nwcc.sourceforge.net/), to understand how a C compiler is parsing that line.

Answer (score 0):

> I am actually bothered about how dynamic memory allocation is actually working in this code.

### Read first [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) or some other good book about *C*

then see [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). Late, read for example some C17 draft standard, e.g. [n2176](https://files.lhmouse.com/standards/ISO%20C%20N2176.pdf). It is specifying the behavior of [malloc(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html). Read also more about the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), [automatic variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_variable), and [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation).

> This approach is new to me as I couldn't find any resource that could explain this code.

Consider studying the source code of [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). It is *implementing* `malloc` (on Linux, above [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) such as [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)...)

And read also a good [operating system textbook](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/). You might understand how `malloc` works on ordinary OSes. It is related to [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) since *sometimes* `malloc` is growing that space.

Read of course the documentation of your C compiler (e.g. [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)). Enable all warnings and debug info, so use `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Then read the documentation of your debugger (e.g. [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)) and run your program step by step under your debugger.

**BTW, your code is wrong:** both [malloc(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) and [scanf(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) could fail, and you don't check that.

At last, **take inspiration from existing *open source* software** coded in C, like [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) or [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) or [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) or [GTK](https://gtk.org/).

---

### C and C++ are different programming languages

Your question mentions C++. **C and C++ are very different**. For C++, read first a good [C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html). Then see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp). Later, take inspiration from existing C++ open source software, such as [fish](https://fishshell.com/), [Qt](https://qt.io/), [FLTK](https://fltk.org/), [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) and many others on [github](https://github.com/).

---

### Consider using static source code analyzer tools

Such as [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/), the [Clang static analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), and in 2021 perhaps [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/).

Comment: Since OP is new, jumping straight to the standard & libc sources looks like a huge overkill, it's almost impossible to learn the basics of the language this way.

Comment: Yes, so I recommend to **read first *Modern C***. Be aware that I am not a native English speaker, so feel free to improve the phrasing

Comment: What does the line ```a = (int (*)[col])malloc(n * col * sizeof(int));``` do ? Can someone explain please.

Comment: Yes. Spend several days in reading a good C programming book. You'll understand that line once you did read and understood it